# nivo slider - loading gif keeps on and on and on

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

i have done 'everything' that manual says.
included all files, adding it properly to html structure, loaded images,..

please, you can view live problem [here](http://lookaroundyou.net)

Comment: Where us the #slider container?

Comment: what do you mean where? it's right there

Comment: Do you have a `div` with `id=slider` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ajaxpage` to load the `div` with `id=slider` for certain categories for `page.php`.  However, Nivo slider is looking for a div after the primary page has loaded (the `$(window).load` function).

Somehow, you need to attach the `.load` function call to the page being loaded by `ajaxpage`.

You might try adding the `$(window).load` call to the bottom of each page whenever you are setting up a Nivo slideshow.

If you were using jQuery's ajax library/module calls, you might be able to attach the `load` action to fire when the ajax has loaded.

I looked at the source of one of your `page.php` pages with Nivo and I think that you set up the HTML correctly, but the Nivo module just has not been started, partly because of the way the page is pulling in the content using ajax.

This is a clever way of doing things, but just needs a different trick to starting Nivo.

Comment: i have tried adding it at the bottom of loaded page but without success

Comment: what if i put it inside iframe#slider and try to use its onload event? you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hello Daniel, it just occurred to me, are you linking to nivo and jquery on page.php? page.php may have to be self-contained.  I have used nivo before, which is why your problem caught my curiosity.

Comment: About iframe, this is an alternative, but the ajax approach gives you more control over events.  I would try jQuery's ajax load function also.

Comment: please if you are familiar with jquery i would be grateful for a tip

Comment: many thanks Marc. sorry for forgetting to tip you ;) my mind is all over the place

Comment: Thank you Daniel, by reposting the question, you got a very good answer, and I also learned something new, since I was not quite sure how to fix the original problem.  I appreciate the tick mark.  Good luck with the website!