# jquery load() after ajax page is loaded - howto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nivo-slider

i have following lines included at the bottom of my index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="class/jquery-1.4.3.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="class/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

problem lies in `$(window).load` ...
index.php's body is updated onload through ajax call which delivers div#slider upon matching. this makes it `nivoSlider()` not executing. do you have any trick to make this thing work. i do prefer non-jquery way around it, but at the end of the day anything helps.

many thanks

[WEBPAGE IS HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net)

Comment: This question stems from an earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370247/nivo-slider-loading-gif-keeps-on-and-on-and-on in which I identified the source of the problem, which allowed Daniel to pose the question and get a detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the call in the callback for the AJAX load.

```
$('.something').load( 'http://www.example.com/foo', function() {
     $(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

Example using your code (for body):

```
$(function() { // run on document ready, not window load
     $('#content').load( 'page.php?c=2&limit=5', function() {
           $(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider();
     });
});
```

For link:

```
<!-- updates links like so -->
<a class='nav' href='page.php?category=art&limit=5&c=1'>art</a>

// in the same document ready function
     $('a.nav').click( function() {
          var $link = $(this);
          $('#content').load( $link.attr('href'), function() {
               $(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider();
               $link.addClass('selected'); // instead of setting bg directly to #828282;
          });
          return false; // to prevent normal link behavior
     });
```

Comment: @tvanfosson, he is not using the jquery ajax methods.. (*although he should*)

Comment: what if don't use jquery for ajax loads which i don't?(but i might if u tell me there is no way around it)

Comment: how do you tell jquery's ajax call to set results in specific container? please check my body onload call and give me jquery alternative. i don't really care at this moment

Comment: @daniel -- I would recommend using jQuery for it if you are using jQuery otherwise.  If not, there's nothing special about jQuery's use of callbacks.  You just need to add the ability to pass in a function that gets executed when the AJAX call is complete, the function should invoke the jQuery snippet (probably just `$('#slider')...` instead of the scope-limited call) to load up the slider.

Comment: this is awesome work. it totally made it work and changed my perspective on using js libraries. i guess those are life savers when u have a small kid and wife to take care of

Comment: @tvanfosson Can you or someone add the "nivo" tag to this question?  This is a good trick for advanced nivo applications.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not want to use $(document) rather than $(window)?

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
```

or shorthand

```
    $(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
```